# grepping variables containing special characters in a shell script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

I am trying to grep out some lines from a file based on patterns stored in a variable in bash script that may contain `(`, `)`, `[` or `]`. I get the desired output with patterns that do not contain the special characters but with `(` or `)`, I get a blank output and with `[` or `]`, I get the following error:
grep: range out of order in character class

Sample of pattern file:

```
14-3-3-like protein B
14-3-3-like protein B (Fragment)
3-oxoacyl-[acyl-carrier-protein] synthase 2
```

Sample of input file:

```
seq1    gi|703124372    380    285    +    2e-154    14-3-3-like protein B    sp
seq2    Q96451    69    51    +    3e-16    14-3-3-like protein B (Fragment)    sp
seq3    P0AAI5    104    84    -    4e-20    3-oxoacyl-[acyl-carrier-protein] synthase 2    sp
```

My code is as below:

```
if [ $@==0 ]
    then echo -e "\nUSAGE: $0 [pattern file] [in file] > [out file]\n"
    exit;
else
    while read line; do
            echo -e "Pattern: $line"
            grep -P "\t$line\t" $2
            echo -e "\n"
    done < $1
```

Sample of the output:

```
Pattern: 14-3-3-like protein B 
seq1    gi|703124372    380    285    +    2e-154    14-3-3-like protein B    sp
Pattern: 14-3-3-like protein B (Fragment)    sp
Pattern: 3-oxoacyl-[acyl-carrier-protein] synthase 2
grep: range out of order in character class
```

I've tried using grep -Fw but that also doesn't give the desired output..
I've also tried substituting the patterns in the two input files with `\(` and `\[` instead of `(` and `[` but that also doesn't work..

Any idea how can I achieve this? Is there anything else I could use instead of grep?

Comment: Maybe escape the characters with a backslash?

Comment: Thanks, have added the samples.. Hope my question is clear..

Comment: Oh I've tried that but with that if my pattern is "14-3-3-like protein", all lines containing the pattern are grepped which also includes patterns like "14-3-3-like protein B" despite the -F option.. So my workaround was to use tabs as pattern boundary..

Comment: ok use: `grep -F $'\t'"$line"$'\t' "$2"`

Comment: Yes, this works well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tab=$(echo -e \\t)
grep -F "$tab$line$tab" $2
```

Edit:
See also the suggestion from @anubhava: `grep -F $'\t'"$line"$'\t' "$2"`

Comment: @MeetaSunil  You should accept the solution and upvote it if you're ok with the answer. It will award you a badge and other users who look up your problem can see it's solved.